# Entering value in sublist if empty

Tags: python, list, sublist

So I have a larger for loop which produces nested lists of various of sizes: e.g.

```
[[6], [3], [5], [3, 2, 5, 3], [5], [6, 5, 4], [5, 3, 2]]
[[5], [], [], [4], [3]]
[[5], [2]]
[[], [4], [3, 2, 4]
```

In short, I would like it so that each array that has an empty sublist to simply be the value 0. So like :
 If the list generated is :
    `[[6], [3], [5], [3, 2, 5, 3], [5], [6, 5, 4], [5, 3, 2]]`

Then I would keep it that way.

But if the list generated is:`[[5], [], [], [4], [3]]`

Then I would like it to be:
`[[5], [0], [0], [4], [3]]`

Likewise, for the final row above, I would want it to be:`[[0], [4], [3, 2, 4]`

I have been trying something along the lines of :

```
for k in range(0,len(TempAisle)):
           if TempAisle[k][0] == None:
               TempAisle[k][0]= 0
 k+=1
```

But I am getting an `list index out of range` error.

It seems to be a rather simple problem and have seen others who have asked ways to check if there is a sublist that is empty but I am having trouble replacing it with another value (0 in my case). Any help and explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: `if TempAisle[k][0] == None:` asks if the first value of the kth sublist **is equal to the value `None`**. You want to check if the *sublist* is equal to an empty list, i.e. `[]`. Fundamentally, your misconception seems to arise out of an assumption that if you index into an empty list you will get `None` if the values don't exit, but instead, you get an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate on the items directly - the more **Pythonic** way - no need to use `range`. Test for the truthiness of each of the items (empty lists are *falsy*), and append a zero only if the sublist is empty:

```
for x in TempAisle:
    if not x:
        x.append(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, but what exactly is the difference between appending the value 0 and not making it equivalent to 0?

Comment: @PythonQuestions You don't need to test if it's equivalent to anything. Sufficient to know the list is empty; if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye i think the question was "why `x.append(0)` rather than `x = [0]`", and the answer is that only the former actually changes an element of `TempAisle`, while the later only changes the temporary variable `x`.

Comment: Yeah I was just wanting to know why would x.append(0) in your solution work whereas x = 0 wouldn't. Is there a reason why append is used in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @PythonQuestions Assignment in the for loop only binds the name used by the iteratee (`x` here) to a new list. It does not modify the initial reference. However, since `.append` is accessed via the original/pure/unmodified reference `x` which points to our sublist, it updates the list.

Answer (score 3):

For a one-line solution:

```
x = [elem or [0] for elem in TempAisle]
```

An EDIT based on the comment of @Moses Koledoye, to avoid creating a new list, but to keep it as a one-line solution:

```
[x.append(0) for x in TempAisle if not x]
```

Comment: Cool one-liner, but it is not always desirable to set-up a new list, especially when it's a list of lists and there is no explicit requirement for a new one.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's the force of habit, working with small lists, few variables... But in other situations can be a bad idea. Good call.